# Using string and Array to redo a text into a "headertext"

Tags: arrays, string, assert

im a student and cant figure out how to get this right.
I have the text in str1 = "this is a test"
and str2 = " THIS IS A TEST"

i want them both to become "This Is A Test"

```
void convertToRubrik(char str[])
{
char arr[20];

for(int i=0; i<14; i++)
{
    arr[i]=str[i];
}

    for(int k=0; k<14; k++)
    {
    if(!isspace(arr[k]))
    {
        arr[k]=toupper(arr[k]);
    }
    if(isspace(arr[k]))
    {
        arr[k]=toupper(arr[k]);
    }
    else
    {
        arr[k]=tolower(arr[k]);
    }
    cout<<arr[k]<<endl;;
    }
}



void autoConvertToRubrik()
{
    char str1[] ="this is a test";
    char str2[] ="THIS IS A TEST";

    char rubrik[]="This Is A Test";

    convertToRubrik(str1);
    convertToRubrik(str2);

    assert( isSame(str1 , rubrik));
    assert( isSame(str2 , rubrik));

}
```

ive been trying for a couple of hours now and i cant figure it out....

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`convertToRubrik()` does not change the original string, and does not return anything. It creates a new array inside it, prints it to the screen, then throws it away.

You need it to either return `arr[]` and update the calling code, or take a pointer to `str[]` and update it in-place.